# HashSet adding same list objects 2 times

Tags: java, hash, hashset

I am new the the java HashSet and having problem understanding the following thing.
In HashSet duplicate objects are not allowed, and when we try to add duplicate objects it gives false as output.

However, when I tried adding same list object 2 times in a HashSet, and it successfully added it.

Here is the code I've written.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(example());
    }

    public static List<List<Integer>> example() {
        Set set = new HashSet();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4));
        set.add(list);
        list.add(33);
        System.out.println(set.add(list));
        return set.stream().toList();
    }
```

The line number 11 gives **true** as output, whereas it should've given **false** as I have added the **same list object**.

```
true
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 33], [1, 2, 3, 4, 33]]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why is it giving true as output?

Comment: I suggest that you step into HashSet.add with the debugger and find out why this happens.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you *changed* the list after inserting it into the set. Once you do that, the behavior of the set is unspecified.

As documented in the javadocs for [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html):

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set.

This is an oversimplification, but what probably happened is when you first inserted the list, the set looks at its hash code and puts it in a corresponding bucket. Then you insert again, and this time the list has a different hash code, so the set puts it into another bucket, causing the same list be inserted twice.

The correct behaviour of the set depends on the fact that objects are not changed (in such a way that affects `equals`) once they are put into the set.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` uses `HashMap` under the hood, which uses the `hashCode` of the object to find the bucket for it. After you added an element to the `List`, its `hashCode` changed, which resulted in it being identified as a different object.

You could use `IdentityHashMap` instead if you want reference equality and the hash code from `System.identityHashCode`.

```java
Set<List<Integer>> set = Collections.newSetFromMap(new IdentityHashMap<>());
```

With this `set`, the `List` will only be added once.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple answer

Add a :

```java
System.out.println(list.hashCode());
```

*before and after* `list.add(..)` ;)

##### Explanation

It is a "*hash* set". (While testing `list == list` probably useless.)